# BufferedWriter only writing first word in android

Tags: android, file-io

I have the following code to write to a file:

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(out);


writer.write("Input String"); //Enter the string here
writer.newLine();
writer.write("Input String 2"); //Enter the string here

writer.close();
```

What I want it to output is

```
Input String
Input String 2
```

What I get is just the word `Input`

Does anyone know how to fix this issue so I can write multiple lines to a file?

Comment: Try to call `flush` method on BufferedWriter object.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this..

```
 public class BufferedWriterDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      StringWriter sw =null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;
      String s = "Hello World!!";

      try{
         // create new string writer
         sw = new StringWriter();

         // create new buffered writer
         bw = new BufferedWriter(sw);

         // write string sequence to buffered writer
         bw.write(s, 0, 5);

         // write new line to the buffered writer
         bw.newLine();

         // write the next string sequence to buffered writer
         bw.write(s, 6, s.length()-6);

         // releases all bytes to the underlying stream
         bw.flush();

         // print
         System.out.print(sw.getBuffer());

      }catch(Exception e){

         // if any I/O error occurs
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{

         // releases system resources from the streams
         if(sw!=null)
            sw.close();
         if(bw!=null)
            bw.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The close method blocks until all resources are free. The documentation says:

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it.

There is no gurantee as for the content of the data.
I suggest you call flush before closing the stream.